# AEM 6.2 create common content to reuse on multiple pages

Tags: aem

I am new to AEM and know that AEM is based on pages. I am wondering if there is any functionality available using which an Author can create a common content snippet once and reuse on multiple pages. Please suggest.

Comment: If the common content is just text, then look into the [Content Fragments](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-2/assets/using/content-fragments.html) feature available in AEM 6.2. If it is content with design and layout, then you have [Experience Fragments](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/authoring/using/experience-fragments.html), but it is available only in AEM 6.3

Comment: @rakhi4110, I believe we can move this comment to a suitable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the scope of reuse, you have option of:

- Content fragments (as mentioned above) which is available from 6.2+
- Sling content reference which has always been there.
- iParsys, normally used for common content like header, footer, log etc.
- Authorable templates can be a crude implementation for content sharing depending on requirement. For example, log can be part of template.

Experience Fragments are much better due to cache management in 6.3.

It all depends on use case but there are several answers and approaches so you will need to pick the best fit for your project.

Answer (score 1):

If the common content is just text, then you can use the [Content Fragments](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-2/assets/using/content-fragments.html) feature available in AEM 6.2.

If it is content with design and layout, then you have [Experience Fragments](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/authoring/using/experience-fragments.html). However, Experience Fragments are available only from AEM 6.3.